# PHP Commenting System Has Fallen Apart

Tags: php, mysql, html, system, comments

I have a problem with my syntax. I don't know how to complete the following. I have built a member system that allows viewers to register and login and view my site. I wanted to make a commenting system so people can comment on stuff. I have built a test commenting system and it seems to run fine without the user information in place. However, if I try to build a page just like the other pages for my user system and include my commenting system it breaks down because of syntax error. I don't mean like the won't coexist, they are, but stuff conflicts with other stuff and posting a comment doesn't include retrieved user information from mysql database and I can't define ranks to where the user can edit his/her post or remove their post without modifying the other posts and the admin should be able to do it all. I have no idea on what went wrong or how to fix it. I am ready to send information your way, but I have no idea what you may need so I will post anything you need if you ask for it.

```
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
session_start();
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$person = $_SESSION['person'];
$rank = $_SESSION['rank'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Guestbook 2 | Harley's Digital Portfolio</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
//connect to member database and retrieve user information
require("./connect2.php");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' ");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($numrows == 1){
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $username = $row['username'];
    $fullname = $row['fullname'];
    $fullname = $row['fullname'];
    $fullname = $row['fullname'];
    $rank = $row['rank'];

    if (!$fullname){
        $person = $username;
        $_SESSION['person'] = $person;
    }
    else
        $person = $fullname;
        $_SESSION['person'] = $person;
}

mysql_close();
?>
<?php
//Connect to the database
require("./connect.php");

//Page Header
echo "<h2>Guestbook | Harley's Digital Portfolio</h2> Welcome $person, you are ranked as: $rank. <a href='./postguestbook.php'>Post Comment</a> <br/>";
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM guestbook ORDER BY id DESC");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($numrows > 0){
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $dbid = $row['id'];
        $dbname = $row['name'];
        $dbemail = $row['email'];
        $dbmessage = $row['message'];
        $dbtime = $row['time'];
        $dbdate = $row['date'];
        $dbip = $row['ip'];

        $id = $dbid;
        $name = $dbname;
        $message = $dbmessage;
        $time = $dbtime;
        $date = $dbdate;
        $message = nl2br($message);

        $form = "<form action='./guestbook2.php' method='post'><div>
        By $id <b>$name</b> at <b>$time</b> on <b>$date</b> $removebutton <br/>
        $message
        </div> <hr/></form>";
        echo "$form";

    }
}
else
    echo "No posts found.";

    $removebutton = "<input type='submit' name='removebtn' value='X'/>";
    if ($_POST['removebtn']){
        mysql_query("SELECT * FROM guestbook WHERE id='$id'");
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM guestbook WHERE id='$id'");
        echo "Message Removed.";
    }


//Disconnect from database
mysql_close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The above is my guestbook2.php, the below is the postguestbook.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
session_start();
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$person = $_SESSION['person'];
$rank = $_SESSION['rank'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Post to Guestbook | Harley's Digital Portfolio</title>

</head>

<body>
<?php
//connect to member database and retrieve user information
require("./connect2.php");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' ");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($numrows == 1){
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $username = $row['username'];
    $rank = $row['rank'];

    if (!$fullname){
        $person = $username;
        $_SESSION['person'] = $person;
    }
    else
        $person = $fullname;
        $_SESSION['person'] = $person;
}

mysql_close();
?>
<?php
//Connect to the database
require("./connect.php");

//Page Header
echo "<h2>Post to Guestbook | Harley's Digital Portfolio</h2>";

if ($_POST['postbtn']){
    $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
    $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);

    if ($name && $email && $message){
        if ( (strlen($email) >= 7) && (strstr($email, "@")) && (strstr($email, "."))){
            // add to the database
            $time = date("h:i A");
            $date = date("F d, Y");
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

            mysql_query("INSERT INTO guestbook VALUES ('', '$name', '$email', '$message', '$time', '$date', '$ip')");
            echo "You message was posted successfully, <a href='./guestbook2.php'>Go back to Comments</a>";
        }
        else
            echo "You did not enter a valid email address.";
    }
    else
        echo "You did not enter all the required info.";
}

echo    "<form name='postmessage' action='./postguestbook.php' method='post'>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Name:</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='name' style='width: 200px;'/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='email' style='width: 200px;'/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Message:</td>
    <td><textarea  name='message' style='width: 200px; height: 200px;'></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type='submit' name='postbtn' value='Post'/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>";

//Disconnect from database
mysql_close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

There is no errors it just won't show up.. It worked separately before I tried to implement my user system and now I can't get it to where the user can edit or remove his post and the admin can do it all.

Thanks for looking at this post and answering. 
Harley

Comment: Can you share any code from your problem?

Comment: Can you provide some code so someone can spot your syntax error please?

Comment: Copy the errors you receive and paste them here. Also include the lines of code (and surrounding lines) that are mentioned in the error (it will give a line number in the error message).

Comment: Note that you say there is a syntax error, and no errors. Which is it? If syntax error, what is the exact error?

Comment: There is no actual post of a syntax error, but somewhere in my lines of coding I have screwed up to where it seems okay on the outside, but the oreo cookie filling is gone.

Comment: no one uses guestbooks anymore :D

Comment: Watch out, I see a potential SQL Injection vulnerability!

Comment: Grigor that is a given, but I named it that when trying to rebuild my comment system so I named it different so I could tell which is which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first like to start off by thanking everyone who posted an answer or comment that was helpful, but I fixed my error. Here is what has been going on:

It wouldn't retrieve the user information from the database after I impletemented my member system into an already built comment system that was using just a name variable and not a user variable. That was mistake number one, see you type in your name and email and message then it would post. Nice and easy. Now when I changed the name variable to the username variable, the MYSQL database was not updating with the correct username information that should have been gathered when you first enter the comment page hence the if username and userid function.

Mistake number to was trying to include everything under one roof (). That didn't work so well because the while loop was interfering. What I did was rewrite the entire page starting with the member system content and then built off of it separating it into multiple  tags. That fixed the retrieval errors that I haven't been seeing because there was nothing to retrieve. Once that was completed then I created a separate page called delete.php that will connect to the database and when you press the remove button it will open $removelink = "Remove"; variable. Inside the delete.php is

```
<?php
require("./connect2.php");
$removeid = $_GET['id'];
mysql_query("DELETE FROM comments WHERE id='$removeid'");
header("location: comments.php");
?>
```

That will then delete the post from the database and go back to the main page. It all works and everything is okay. I have all the pages fixed and if anybody wants to know how I did it please don't hesitate to email me. I would be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your problem exactly cause your description is a bit obscure. Here's some observations though:

guestbook2.php -

$removebutton is never defined. What is this?

`echo "$form";` is unnecessary. Just `echo $form;` if you MUST echo html in php. In your case since you are running all php inline    you should break out of php ?> and place normal html in the    conditional. It is just more readable this way and you won't have to    escape slashes.

```
if ($_POST['removebtn']){
    mysql_query("SELECT * FROM guestbook WHERE id='$id'");
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM guestbook WHERE id='$id'");
    echo "Message Removed.";
}
```

this doesn't make sense. You are querying guestbook, doing nothing with the results and then deleting? Why not just delete? In any case, you are not checking to see if $id is even defined, which it is not in this case unless $numrows is greater than zero. That alone could cause problems since you are supposed to be referencing $_POST['id'] at least so you don't just can whatever the last instance of $id was.

You shouldn't be running queries with blindly accepted session vars either. look into mysql_real_escape_string() to help prevent the horrible security holes in trusting $_SESSION vars, get post or any others the user can spoof as well.

Again, I don't know what your whole problem is cause I can't see the error myself and I don't know what you're getting back from the code, so these are just pointers that may be at least part of the problem.